# How can I compare 2 widgtes in tkinter on positon bevor mapping?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm working on a tool to visualize a piping system. The number of pipes depends on the use case. As a result, there are many different scenarios for mapping. The pipes are numbered. There's a special case where 2 widgets are in a specific position. In this case, there should be a different sequence of numbers. How can I compare the position of the widgets and, depending on the result, change the sequence or not? I tried to compare the position, but then I realized that you can only compare the position after mapping. All of this should happen before mapping.

I think through the picture it is clare. if the number 1 widget is on the same position as the number 9 widget the sequenz of numbers needs to change.

[current version of the visualization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SZcw5.png)

Do you have any ideas on how I can compare properties of the widgets and, depending on the results, take different actions?

Comment: In short: You don;t compare properties of the widgets, you have your pipe information stored in class instances, including their position, then use this information to position the widgets.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Make each pipe an instance of a class that has a position, then implement a method that checks if the pipes have the same position.

When making the widgets use the position information inside the pipe intances to place them.

This is an example, in your real code you shouldn't have each pipe in a separate variable, but have a list of pipes or some other data structure to store them.

```
class Pipe:
    def __init__(self, pos):
        self.pos = pos
    def same_position(other):
        return self.pos == other.pos
  
pipe1 = Pipe(2)  
pipe2 = Pipe(3)
pipe3 = Pipe(2)

print(pipe1.same_position(pipe2))
# prints False

print(pipe1.same_position(pipe3))
# prints True

if pipe1.same_position(pipe3):
    # action to do if both pipes are at the same position
else:
    # action to do if both pipes are at different positions
```